# Can't connect to Mysql on Centos from remote machine

Tags: mysql, centos

CentOS release 6.3 (Final)

Name        : MySQL

Arch        : x86_64

Version     : 5.1.67

All of this is running on virtualbox under Windows. network adapter is bridged to my LAN adapter. Firewall is open. MySQL is listening

[root@virtualcentos ~]# iptables -L

ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:mysql

lsof -i | grep my

mysqld    2142   mysql   10u  IPv4  14439      0t0  TCP *:mysql (LISTEN)

I can connect to the MySQL server using the LAN IP from the box itself but not from Windows host machine. However I can connect to the SSH and HTTP servers on the same Linux VM just fine.

I've set bind-address in my.cnf to 0.0.0.0 and made sure that skip-networking is not there

user is properly created and granted privileges.

I've added skip-name-resolve to my.cnf just in case.

Otherwise this is a clean vanilla CentOS install inside VirtualBox.

Have I missed something? Why in the world I'm unable to connect to the MySQL server on the VM from the host machine while I can connect to HTTP and SSH?

Comment: You do have `skip-networking` commented. Right?

Comment: yep. skip-networking is commented in /etc/my.cnf. are there any other places it can be hiding in?